# Trigger before insert and trigger after insertion

Tags: sql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a trigger to insert a new row in `DUMPINGGRD` before the insertion in `REPORT`. It works. The issue is the first File_Id created in `DUMPINGGRD` is '0' and when i try to insert another row in `REPORT`, apparently it is trying to create the `File_Id` as '0' again.

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT ( R_Id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
R_Type varchar(255) not null,
R_Title varchar(255) not null,
U_Id int(10) not null,
File_Id int(10) not null,  
PRIMARY KEY (R_Id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

```
 CREATE TABLE `DUMPINGGRD`
(
`File_Id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`File_Name` varchar(255),
`UploadDate` date,
 PRIMARY KEY (`File_Id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE  `REPORT` ADD CONSTRAINT  `fk_report` FOREIGN KEY (`File_Id`)
REFERENCES `DUMPINGGRD` (`File_Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

---

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER ins_File 
BEFORE INSERT ON `REPORT` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `DUMPINGGRD` (`File_Id`) VALUES (NEW.`File_Id`);
END$$
delimiter ;
```

### Thanks!

When i try to insert a new row in `REPORT`, I just hit the error  #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pb`.`report`, CONSTRAINT `fk_report` FOREIGN KEY (`Doc_Id`) REFERENCES `dumpinggrd` (`Doc_Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: that means every time NEW.File_Id=0.meaning you are not passing value to File_Id

Comment: will you show which insert query you are using?

Comment: is there anyway that i can get the last file_id in the db and +1 to it? can i also create another trigger for after insertion in DUMPINGGRD as I'll like to update one of the attribute in DUMPINGGRD that points to the File_Id that was created by the "Before insertion on REPORT" trigger

Comment: yes you can,For that you need to create logic.may i know your datatype used for File_Id used in sql

Comment: Thanks!

CREATE TABLE REPORT
(
R_Id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
R_Type varchar(255) not null,
R_Title varchar(255) not null,
U_Id int(10) not null,
File_Id int(10) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`R_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Insert query meaning? Not too sure about it but I have inserted the trigger that I have created for the "Before insert". Thanks!

Comment: ok i understand.so you need to insert 1,2,3,... in File_id for each executing of insert statement.Right?

Comment: @Ajay Yes! Thanks! The File_id that is created will also be stored in the REPORT as well

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   delimiter $$ CREATE TRIGGER ins_File BEFORE INSERT ON REPORT FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
set @filenum=(Select max(File_Id) from DUMPINGGRD);  

if(@filenum=0) then  --checking whether record is present or not
begin
new.File_Id=1;--if no record is present then set file_id=1 
end;
else
new.File_Id=@filenum+1;--if record is present then set file_id=Maxvalue+1;
end if; 
    INSERT INTO DUMPINGGRD (File_Id) VALUES (NEW.File_Id);
     END$$ delimiter ;
```

Comment: right now i dont have sql workbench in my laptop.so if any syntax errors are there.i need to check once again.but logic is perfect.

Comment: Thanks! Have inserted the code but there is no row created in Dumpinggrd. Will try to figure out first while looking forward to your reply. By the way, can i also find out if the trigger will be an issue as File_Id in Dumpinggrd is actually the primary key and File_Id in REPORT is actually a foreign key that points to it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm really sorry but I'm still unable to get the trigger to insert into Dumpinggrd. Will you able to shed some light? Thanks!